Why is it valid to reorder the variables in the implicit function theorem? Doesn't that change the function?


$\textbf{Theorem 2.10.14 (The implicit function theorem).}$ Let $ W $ be an open neighborhood of $ c \in \mathbb{R}^n $, and let $ \textbf{F} : W \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k} $ be a differentiable function, with $ \textbf{F(c)} = 0 $ and $ [\textbf{DF(c)}] $ onto.
Order the variables in the domain so that the matrix consisting of the first $ n-k $ columns of $ [\textbf{DF(c)}] $ row reduces to the identity. ...

I get that the purpose of this is to permute the columns of the jacobian matrix so that the first n-k form an invertible matrix, but what does this do to the function? Doesn't that change the domain, and hence the function?

@xxxxxxxxx But doesn't that change the fact that F is defined on W? Like if c = (1, 2,  3), but we needed to switch the 2nd and 3rd variables, then would c still be (1, 2, 3) or would it be (1, 3, 2). Would the domain still be the same. I'm confused about how this works.

@xxxxxxxxx if you rewrite those elements doesn't that amount to changing W?

@xxxxxxxxx so would it be like composing the function F with a permutation function σ, going through the theorem for this new function, and then composing the result with σ^-1?

@xxxxxxxxx I mean that if the variables of F are in the 'wrong order'  we compose F with a permutation, σ, to get G = F○σ, and apply the theorem to G. Then, at the end, we get F(σ(g(y), y)) = 0 in equation 2.10.28.

@xxxxxxxxx sorry, "composing the result" was a mistake. I mean what I said in my last comment. Because reordering the variables is equivalent to composing the function with a permutation function.

Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is why.

@ArturoMagidin apologies. I have edited the post.

Which book do you use?

If you merely assume that $DF(c)$ is surjective, then yes, you will have to change the function to a new one $F\circ\sigma$ in order for their proof to go through. This isn’t any real loss of generality though because $\sigma$ is a linear isomorphism, so any statement you can make for $F$, you can make a corresponding statement for $F\circ \sigma$, and vice-versa.

The domain of $\mathbf{F}$ is $W \subset \Bbb{R}^n$.  So $\mathbf{F}$ receives a point of $\Bbb{R}^n$.  Points of $\Bbb{R}^n$ are just points -- they don't have coordinates until we pick an origin and select a basis.
Consider $p \in W$.  For different choices of origin+basis, we expect the coordinates of $p$ to be different.  However, coordinates are a convenience for humans; $\mathbf{F}$ receives the point $p$ as input and is blind to the coordinates we scaffold up for our convenience.  Consequently, we are free to choose coordinates to make our computations easier.

But if the coordinates for F are in the 'wrong order' (as in, the pivotal columns don't come first) does it technically amount to considering a different function G = F○σ where σ is a permutation? This shouldn't change the rest of the theorem, but equation 2.10.28 would then be F(σ(g(y), y)) = 0.

$F$ doesn't take coordinates.  $F$ takes points.  Coordinates are entirely made up -- they are a convenient way to label points, but points are not coordinates, points don't have an order of coordinates, and $F$ is blind to the coordinates we make up to label points.
